# the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, openlayers

In this url( url: 'Data/countries.geojson') fetch geojson data from folder. after run this program showing error is  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

```
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'Data/countries.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
       crossOrigin: null
    })
  });
  map.addLayer(vector);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiKVw.png)

Comment: that means `Data/countries.geojson` doesn't exist - perhaps the file isn't in the folder `Data` (case sensitive) that exists in the folder the html file is in

Comment: You may need to add a `/` in front of `Data`.

Comment: What is you dir structure? Check network tab and look for this request and check it's url. My guess is that this url points to `localhost:44383/vectorlayer.html/Data/countries.geojson`. If that is the case then add `/` at the beginning of your url property like `url: '/Data/countries.geojson'`

Comment: If you are using IIS for your localhost you will probably need to add `.geojson` to the MIME types (or you could rename to `.json` which should be a predefined type).